# Преобразовать вид чисел в датасете

Tags: python, pandas

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как уйти от формата чисел с планавающей точкой к адекватно вопринимаемому глазу виду?
Кроме переменной `order_count`, все имеют тип `float`.

Comment: Сначала объясните, что это вообще такое и каким образом вы получили такую картинку

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста,  что такое "адекватно вопринимаемый глазом вид числа"? Я, например, вполне адекватно воспринимаю шестнадцатеричные числа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по картинке речь идет о выводе метода [DataFrame.describe()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html).

```
In [6]: df
Out[6]:
              a       b           c
0  123456789012  123456  1234567890
1  123456789012  123456  1234567890
2  123456789012  123456  1234567890
3  123456789012  123456  1234567890
4  123456789012  123456  1234567890
5  123456789012  123456  1234567890
6  123456789012  123456  1234567890
7  123456789012  123456  1234567890
8  123456789012  123456  1234567890
9  123456789012  123456  1234567890

In [7]: df.describe()
Out[7]:
                  a         b             c
count  1.000000e+01      10.0  1.000000e+01
mean   1.234568e+11  123456.0  1.234568e+09
std    0.000000e+00       0.0  0.000000e+00
min    1.234568e+11  123456.0  1.234568e+09
25%    1.234568e+11  123456.0  1.234568e+09
50%    1.234568e+11  123456.0  1.234568e+09
75%    1.234568e+11  123456.0  1.234568e+09
max    1.234568e+11  123456.0  1.234568e+09
```

Можно воспользоваться [pd.set_option('display.float_format', ...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html):

```
In [8]: pd.set_option('display.float_format', lambda x: '%.3f' % x)

In [9]: df.describe()
Out[9]:
                     a          b              c
count           10.000     10.000         10.000
mean  123456789012.000 123456.000 1234567890.000
std              0.000      0.000          0.000
min   123456789012.000 123456.000 1234567890.000
25%   123456789012.000 123456.000 1234567890.000
50%   123456789012.000 123456.000 1234567890.000
75%   123456789012.000 123456.000 1234567890.000
max   123456789012.000 123456.000 1234567890.000
```

Answer (score 0):

`dataset['first_order_original_price'] = float(dataset['first_order_original_price'])`